# trying to add rewrite_rule to query_vars

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add rewrite rule to query_vars but it is not working.
currently the permalink is looking like this:

```
localhost/mysite/?detail=value
```

but i want it to look like this:

```
localhost/mysite/value
```

here is my code:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'do_queryvars' );
function do_queryvars( $qvars ) {
$qvars[] = 'detail';
return $qvars;
}

function do_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $new_rules = array('detail/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?detail=$matches[1]');
    $rules = $new_rules + $rules;
    return $rules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'do_rewrite_rules');
```

link:

```
<a href="?detail=<?php echo $value; ?>" >Link</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your Rewrite Rule function, you should call your link like this

```
http://localhost/mysite/detail/value
```

Comment: Ahh Thanks man i was actually missing /detail/ in link. 
Thanks again for your perfect answer.